# Why does the width of a DOM element change with fixed positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have an HTML Table for which I am trying to implement a Sticky fixed header. The table has over 100 rows and columns so that it scrolls on both the horizontal and vertical.

For this, I need to set the position of the header element to 'Fixed', but doing so changes the width of the element, causing several `<td>` elements to be cut off on the right side of the `<div>` it is in.

[image][image]

This is the table from the right side. With Position:Fixed applied (in the second view), the table header got truncated from the side and only scrolls up to a certain number of columns. There is no left or right margin, and no padding attributes. The table is inside a `<div>` which shares 80% of the screen, with 20% allocated to a second div with another table, as in:

```
#leftPanel {
    width: 20%;
    height: 90vh;
    float: left;
}

#tablePanel {
    width: 80%;
    height: 90vh;
    float:right;
}
```

The table (inside the `#tablepanel` `<div>`) is set up with a standard table structure

```
<table>
<thead class="header">
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<thead class="pseudoHeader"
</thead>
</table>
```

I use a Pseudo header, a clone of the main header, so that the widths of the columns are maintained after setting Position to fixed (another side-effect). The pseudo-header acts as its own scrollable element and reacts to scrolling on the `<tbody>` element.

```
$(".pseudoHeader").css({"top": 0, "position" : "fixed"});
$(".pseudoHeader").css({"overflow-x":"scroll", "max-width":"100%"});
```

After setting these attributes in CSS, the width of the header is reduced and no longer shows all the columns.

My question is, **Why does `position: fixed` changed for the `<thead>` cause this behavior?**

Comment: fixed means ithe position is fixed on the screen. you maybe getting confused between the position and the display attribute -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Can you provide your whole html code? in a fiddle or sth ?

Comment: Yes, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMZXqr 
That's the HTML and CSS. The javascript uses local resources so can't be copied. The demo shows how the top header only scrolls up to a certain point, and then truncates the rest of the content.

Comment: You have two theads in your table, which is not correct. A table can only have one thead and one tfoot. It can have many tbodys though.